# Numerical keyboard in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, textbox

I want to trigger numeric keyboard in some TextBox elements in GWT,
someone have any exapmle for this
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's currently no widget that does this for you, but you can easily do it with a `TextBox` widget:

```
TextBox numberbox = new TextBox();
numberbox.getElement().setPropertyString("type", "number");
```

Or of course if you're not using widgets but HTML snippets directly, e.g. in an `HTMLPanel` in UiBinder:

```
<input type="number" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.
I am using UiBinder, however I tried to use both your suggestions. I could not find a method called "SetProperty" for the Object called Element in the GWT library. There is a method called setPropertyString but it did not suit my needs. 
In addition, I tried to use the tag "input type" like you seggested (with and without the space in the name) and could not get it compiled.
This is the actual XML code for the UiBinder for this TextBox:
`<td>
     <g:TextBox textAlignment='ALIGN_RIGHT' styleName="textBox"
      ui:field="msHovala" />
    </td>`

Comment: Sorry, I indeed meant `setPropertyString` (fixed). If you use `<input type="number" />`, then your `@UiField` would have to be of type `InputElement` or `Element`, and you cannot listen to events directly on the element (you can use _event delegation_ though, listening on a parent element –e.g. the `HTMLPanel`– and then matching on the event's _target_). In one of our projects, we built an `IntegerBox` using a `TextBox` and `setPropertyString`.